# Задача выборов кандидатов

Tags: javascript

У нас есть массив А = [x1, x2, x3, ... k], где находятся количество собранных голосов каждого кандидата . Последный элемент массива k показывает число тех людей которые еще не голосавали.
Нужно найти при данном k количестве сколько кандидатов имеет шанс победить.
Нужно заметить что если для разных кандидатах количество самых высоких результатов одинаковы, означает что победивших нет.
Например в случае А = [2, 3, 5, 2, 3] шансы на победу будут иметь две кандидати А[1] и А[2].
Надо написать функцию которая получает массив А и возвращает количество кандидатов которые имеют шанс на победу.

```
function solution(v, k) {
    k = v[v.length - 1]

    v.sort((a, b) => b - a);

    if (k === 0) {
        return (v[0] == v[1]) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    if (k != 0) {
        let greatestValue = v[0];
        let count = 0;
        v.reverse();
        for (let x = 0; x != v.length; x++) {
            if ((v[x] + k) > greatestValue) count++;
        }
        return count - 1;
    } 
}


console.log(solution([2, 3, 5, 2, 3]));          // 2
console.log(solution([1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0]));       // 0
console.log(solution([5, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0]));       // 1
console.log(solution([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));          // 4
console.log(solution([1, 1, 1, 1, 0]));          // 0
console.log(solution([3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2]));       // 2
console.log(solution([2, 3, 1, 1]));             // получается 0 но должен получатся 1
console.log(solution([2, 3, 4, 8, 6, 1, 7]))     // 5
console.log(solution([5, 5, 5, 0]))              // 0
console.log(solution([1, 2, 3, 4, 2]))           // получается 1 но должен получатся 2
```

Поможете найти ошибку и правильно решить задачу?

Comment: У Вас после сортировки последний элемент оказывается где-то в середине массива и участвует в расчетах.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function solution(v, k) {
 k = v.pop();
 v.sort((a, b) => b - a);

 if (k === 0) {
  return (v[0] == v[1]) ? 0 : 1;
 }

 if (k != 0) {
  let greatestValue = v[0];
  let count = 0;
  v.reverse();
  for (let x = 0; x != v.length; x++) {
   if ((v[x] + k) > greatestValue) count++;
  }
  return count;
 } 
}

console.log(solution([2, 3, 5, 2, 3]));
console.log(solution([1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0]));
console.log(solution([5, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0]));
console.log(solution([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
console.log(solution([1, 1, 1, 1, 0]));
console.log(solution([3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2]));
console.log(solution([2, 3, 1, 1]));
console.log(solution([2, 3, 4, 8, 6, 1, 7]));
console.log(solution([5, 5, 5, 0]));
console.log(solution([1, 2, 3, 4, 2]));
```

Comment: Можно чуть сократить, вместо двух строчек - одну: `k = v.pop();`

Comment: @Yaant спасибо.